# Shunting Yard Algorithm in C# only works some of the time

Tags: c#, tree, expression, postfix-notation

I am working on building an expression tree from an infix expression. Currently I am converting to postfix and then building the tree. My code works for most expressions but not all. I am doing something wrong with my implementation of parentheses. Here is my code-

```
readonly static char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };

       string order_of_op(string op1, string op2)
       {
            if (op1 == "*" || op1 == "/")//is op1 higher?
            {
                return op1;//it is so return it
            }
            else if ((op2 == "*" || op2 == "/"))//is op2 higher
            {
                return op2;//it is so return it
            }
            else
                return op1;// they are both addition or subtraction so    return op1.
        }


        Queue<string> convert_to_postfix(string infix) //following the    Shunting-yard algorithm
        {
            Queue<string> num_queue = new Queue<string>();
            Stack<string> op_stack = new Stack<string>();
            Stack<string> temp_stack = new Stack<string>();
            string temp = "";

            foreach (char s in infix)
            {
                if (operators.Contains(s) == true)//if its a function push it on the stack
                {
                    if (temp != "")//make sure we don't push an empty string
                        num_queue.Enqueue(temp);
                    if (op_stack.Count != 0)//make sure we dont crash popping from empty stack
                    {
                        if (op_stack.Peek() != "(")//if we dont have a parenthese on top proceed as normal
                        {
                            if (op_stack.Count > 1)
                            {
                                while (op_stack.Count != 0 && order_of_op(op_stack.Peek(), s.ToString()) == op_stack.Peek())
                                {
                                    num_queue.Enqueue(op_stack.Pop());
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        op_stack.Push(s.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        op_stack.Push(s.ToString());
                    }

                    temp = "";
                }
                else if (s == '(')
                {
                    op_stack.Push(s.ToString());
                }
                else if (s == ')')
                {
                    if (temp!= "")
                        num_queue.Enqueue(temp);
                    temp = "";
                    while (op_stack.Peek() != "(")
                    {
                        num_queue.Enqueue(op_stack.Pop());
                    }
                    op_stack.Pop();
                    if (op_stack.Count > 1)
                    {
                        if (operators.Contains(op_stack.Peek()[0]) == true)
                        {
                            num_queue.Enqueue(op_stack.Pop());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    temp += s;
                }
            }

            if (temp != "")
            {
                num_queue.Enqueue(temp);
            }

            foreach (string s in op_stack)
            {
                num_queue.Enqueue(s);
            }

            Console.Write("Postfix = ");
            foreach (string s in num_queue)
            {
                Console.Write(s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            return num_queue;
        }
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What's not working? Please make our job of answering as simple as possible.

Comment: It would also be great if you provided some sample input data and how the code is meant to be run. Also your code doesn't compile. It's missing the declaration for `operators`. It's now turning in to a lot of work for us. Please make it easier.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am having issues identifying what expressions it doesn't work for. Some sample expressions that it doesn't work for are (3+3)*5+4*(3-1) and 8/2*8+3*(4+3). I have narrowed it down to being an issue with how I am handling parentheses,

Comment: Also updated main post to include operators

Comment: This isn't a bug-finding service.  Ask a **specific** question.

Answer (score 0):

Well I fixed it! All I had to change was-

```
if (op_stack.Count > 1)
```

to

```
if (op_stack.Count >= 1)
```